# Installing Composer globally for laravel usage?

Tags: php, laravel, installation, global, composer-php

I'm having some trouble with installing composer globally.

I install composer into my 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12' - directory (I'm using WAMP) and make a project in 'C:\wamp\www\project' using the command: `php composer.phar create-project`.

The problem is that I can only use the `php composer.phar` command when I'm in the directory where I installed it (bin\php\php5.4.12), this directory is already in my path variables.

Their is also a composer.bath file including in that directory: `"@ECHO OFF" "php '%~dp0composer.phar' %*"` that should make it global but when I use the composer command in another directory (directory of my project) using `cmd`, a error pops up saying:

> "@ECHO OFF" "php 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\composer.phar... "
>
> "@ECHO OFF" is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

Does anyone have a clue what the problem is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Locate your `php.exe file, it is probably in:

```
C:\wamp\bin

or

C:\wamp\bin\php
```

Create a file (use notepad) `composer.bat` in the same folder and add this line to it:

```
@php C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\composer.phar %*
```

Close and try to run composer from anywhere:

```
cd\
composer --version
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it worked. But one problem, if I type in 'composer install' or any other command it doesn't execute, it only shows all the composer information (options, available commands,..) Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You must be in a directory that has a composer.json file.

Comment: No, the batch file must pass all the command line options! It does not do this currently.

Answer (score 1):

Although correct answer has been already posted, it is noteworthy to mention that there is a windows installer for composer
https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

You can install it just like any other exe file. During installation it will ask for path to php.exe. It is usually located at
    C:\wamp\bin\php\php{php-version}\php.exe

Once installed you'll have to manually enable php_openssl, php_curl, php_socket by clicking on WAMP icon in the taskbar in bottom right. Then in PHP->PHP Extensions just click on the above three extensions to enable them.

You'll also have to enable openssl from all php.ini files by changing
    ;extension=php_openssl.dll
to
    extension=php_openssl.dll
i.e. uncommenting above line by removing ;

Reference:
http://perials.com/install-composer-on-windows-and-wamp/

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/) open command prompt in your windows machine, then execute the commands one by one or create a bat file and execute it. Mind your directory. Best option is :

```
cd C:\
mkdir ComposerSetup
cd ComposerSetup
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Now create a batch file composer.bat and paste the line in it and save:

```
@php C:\ComposerSetup\composer.phar %*
```

Now add C:\ComposerSetup as your Path environment variable. Close the promot. Open a new command prompt and type composer --v. Basically you are running the composer.bat file from your prompt now.

If you want to save the composer.phar and composer.bat file in other location, its okay, just change the directory location properly.